# 'Incorrect integer value' for an SQL Query inside a PHP script

Tags: php, sql, integer

The following query works fine in SQL but not as an SQL Query in PHP for some reason. The error message is as follows:

> Incorrect integer value: 'SELECT id FROM colours WHERE colour = ' for column `databasename`.`numbers`.`col_id` at row  1

```
$redID = "SELECT id FROM colours WHERE colour = $red";

$populate = "INSERT INTO numbers (col_id) VALUES ('$redID')";

$result=$conn->query($populate);
```

[Database Table - numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlarT.png)

[Database Table - colours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woRhh.png)

Comment: Learn to use parameters to pass values into queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your populate query cannot accept an SQL String as a col_id.

```
$redIDSQL = "SELECT id FROM colours WHERE colour = '$red'";
$redIDQuery=$conn->query($redIDSQL);

$redIDArray=array();
while($redIDResult=mysqli_fetch_assoc($redIDQuery)){
    $redIDArray[]=$redIDResult['id'];
}

if(count($redIDArray)>0){
    $populateSQL = "INSERT INTO numbers (col_id) VALUES ('".implode("'),('",$redID)."')";
    $populateQuery=$conn->query($populateSQL);
}else{
    echo "redID could not be found with colour matching ".$red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the above. Hwever  I get the eroor 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' with this code.  To fix it I added a ;  after $redID=$redIDResult['id']    However, now I am getting the error 'Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch() in

Comment: @MrMan Sorry, I assumed you use PDO connection. I've updated my answer.